# My successfulRequestDidReturnObject method does not work when I login

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, restkit

I'm working on a sales application. created a registration and login system that works through Restkit. In my view the login and registration system is working. I check the console and second what I see everything went right. The User to appear in the database. My problem is that I try to use a method so that if the User log in correctly it is redirected to a view that for now has only a single label. However my console returns this error and the application is broken.

```
2015-02-26 17:19:37.164 MeuJavendi[6778:89059] I restkit:RKLog.m:49 RestKit logging initialized...
2015-02-26 17:19:53.992 MeuJavendi[6778:89059] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 POST 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json'
2015-02-26 17:19:54.243 MeuJavendi[6778:89163] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:222 POST 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.2465s mapping=0.0040s total=0.2701s]
2015-02-26 17:19:54.252 MeuJavendi[6778:89059] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fe3e060db40>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'AdsTableViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
```

The method I use to cause the action is this:

```
- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];
    [self.loadingIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    AdsTableViewController *categoriesVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Ad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AdsTableViewController"];
    [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] menuViewControlller] setPaneViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categoriesVC]
                                                                     animated:NO
                                                                   completion:nil];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

***however my storyboard is configured for the right table view***

This is the login of the complete code:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import "AdsTableViewController.h"


@interface LoginViewController () <JVWebServiceDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *signInButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *forgotPasswordButton;

- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.emailTextField.delegate = self;
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self;

    //    [self setupFonts];
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([self shouldEnableScrollViewOnIphone4S]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 60);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([self shouldEnableScrollViewOnIphone4S]) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}



- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [JVUtils showMessage:error.localizedDescription withTitle:@"Erro"];
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:nil];
    [self.loadingIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {
    if (!(self.emailTextField.text.length > 0)) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"O campo e-mail não pode ficar em branco" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
        [self.emailTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (!(self.passwordTextField.text.length > 0)) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"O campo senha não pode ficar em branco" withTitle:@"Opa!"];
        [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self.loadingIndicatorView startAnimating];

        [[JVWebService sharedService] setServiceDelegate:self];
        [[JVWebService sharedService] getUserForEmail:self.emailTextField.text andPassword:self.passwordTextField.text];
    }
}


- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];
    [self.loadingIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    AdsTableViewController *categoriesVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Ad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AdsTableViewController"];
    [[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] menuViewControlller] setPaneViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categoriesVC]
                                                                     animated:NO
                                                                   completion:nil];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}



@end
```

Comment: I had a progress. Added the identity also to StoryBoard ID. He stopped giving errors now put logs in normally and has no more reaction. He does not redirect to my view of ads.

Comment: Your title and tagging of rest kit seem unrelated to the question content (which shows rest kit success and a storyboard issue), so it isn't really clear what you're asking. And you comment says you have made progress so you should update your question to make it more appropriate.